# Construct an object such that one field is the value type corresponding to another key field

Tags: typescript

Basically I need to derive a "Pair" type

e.g.

```js
type Pair<T extends Record<string, string | number>, K extends keyof T> = {
    field: K,
    value: T[K]
}
```

so that given

```js
type Rabbit = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    weight: number
}
```

I'd like to have:

```js
let namePair: Pair<Rabbit, keyof Rabbit> = {
    field: 'name',
    value: 123 //this should fail
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare pair as a mapped type that maps each key to a corresponding pair object:

```
type Pair<T extends Record<string, string | number>> =
  {[K in keyof T]: {field: K, value:T[K]}}[keyof T]
```

If you apply it to `Rabbit`, the result is a union of pairs:

```
type Test = Pair<Rabbit>
// {field: "name", value: string} | {field: "age", value: number} | {field: "weight", value: number}
```

This should give you the desired behavior on single pair declarations:

```
const namePair: Pair<Rabbit> = { field: 'name', value: "Bob" } // ok

const weightPair: Pair<Rabbit> = { field: 'weight', value: 250 } // ok

const badPair: Pair<Rabbit> = { field: 'name', value: 606} // fails
```

And it works on arrays as well:

```
const arr: Pair<Rabbit>[] = []

arr.push({ field: "name", value: "Bob" }) // ok

arr.push({ field: "weight", value: 250 }) // ok

arr.push({ field: "name", value: 606 }) // fails
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBASghgIwQS2FAvFA3gKCvqAOzgFsIAuKAZ2ACdlCBzAGjwLkYqIFcSEJarAlADuEZIwAWwSoV79aOAL44coSFAAKcZLQA8AFSgQAHsAiEAJlVgQAxgHtalvTXpNm1Og0ZQAPjx8AgB8wRhsWADaANJQDFAA1hAgDgBmUAYAupRYqcgQADaWlNGeAG5wBdwUBjGZSkqRSSnpWarq0AYQNBhaOvrwSKjBOAD0owQAegD8qo6EPcRk2rqUKwOIKMBhmFhQeYXFUADkSxDH5ZXVlABEAEIOCDdQSlDjUA4Jcw4LaGIS0nWa36ekGWx22H2%20SKlGO-ykwAuUAqVS4ACYAKwABhebwmn2%20vygCDgliBfV0oM2w16ewOMJOZyRKOuUAAbFi2a93qkdAUqISenBaLRgZSwcNIplelLVMLaAA6MDcKiSAAUdOhRxuZxul1RtweTxeAEo8R8vjh5UqVerNYdbvDpHrkVd0djTeaCVaRTbVRqoQ6oDrSBAXSyuBy2Z6eXyBTggA)

Comment: Thanks, this works!
Though I wonder if Typescript can have the syntax less abstruse/complex

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic type `T` which is a key of `Rabbit`.

```
type RabbitPair<T extends keyof Rabbit> = {
    rabbitField: T
    rabbitValue: Rabbit[T]
}
```

---

```
let field1 : RabbitPair<"name"> = { rabbitField: 'name', rabbitValue: 'Johnny'}
let field2 : RabbitPair<"age"> = { rabbitField: 'age', rabbitValue: 14}
let field3 : RabbitPair<"weight"> = { rabbitField: 'weight', rabbitValue: 'This is not a number'}

function test<T extends keyof Rabbit>(t: RabbitPair<T>){}

test({
  rabbitField: "age",
  rabbitValue: 23 // fails if there is string here
})
```

The solution doesn't work perfectly for arrays though:

```
const arr: RabbitPair<keyof Rabbit>[] = []

arr.push({
  rabbitField: "name",
  rabbitValue: "value" // numbers work here too, but nothing else
})

function push_rabbit<T extends keyof Rabbit>(t: RabbitPair<T>){
  arr.push(t)
}

push_rabbit({
  rabbitField: "name",
  rabbitValue: "value" // numbers don't work here
})
```

Comment: My use case needs an array of such pairs, is it possible to add typing to such array?

Array<RabbitPair<any>> does not seem to work (it doesn't enforce the strict value types)

Comment: @Iceberglet You can just use the function hack and add `[]` to the parameter type

Comment: I can't find a solution for the `array` problem but I put a workaround in the answer. If you hover over `rabbitValue` here you see its `string | number` which is not perfect. But you could write a "proxy" function with the same declaration as the function in my answer which pushes elements into the array.